# How to suppress the display of passwords?

Tags: python, getpass

I need to hide password when user run script in console (like this: `mysql -p`).
For input parameters I use `argparse`, how I can add `getpass` to password parameter?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-p', action='store', dest='password', type=getpass.getpass())
```

When I run my script: `python script.py -u User -p`
I get separate line for enter password (`Password:`), but after entering Exception: `ValueError: 'my_password' is not callable` is raised.

Comment: its common to make a call to `getpass` after `argparse` parsing is complete so that its done after cmd line args have been verified.

Answer (score 8):

This guy should solve your problem: [getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html)

Here is an example with a custom action

```
class PwdAction(argparse.Action):

     def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
         mypass = getpass.getpass()
         setattr(namespace, self.dest, mypass)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', action=PwdAction, nargs=0)
```

Comment: I use it (type=getpass.getpass()) but I need to use it together with argparse

Comment: Care to elaborate? OP is already using getpass. A link to the docs might be useful but it's not really an answer.

Comment: Sorry, did't see. Then I'd create a custom action that prompts the user with getpass in there, let me edit the answer in a moment!

Comment: Beat me to it. I've corrected mine anyway but this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: My previous answer was incorrect and based on a guess. This was my attempt at a working solution. @qwattash posted the answer correctly first but since I spent ten minutes working it out I thought I'd correct my answer.

```
import argparse
import getpass

class Password(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string):
        if values is None:
            values = getpass.getpass()
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-p', action=Password, nargs='?', dest='password')
args = parser.parse_args()

password = args.password #either from command line or from prompt
```

Comment: I've tried, but in this case I take error: error: argument -p: expected one argument. In my solution at least I can run script and take line for input hidden password.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename the process name. Maybe you are looking for this:

```
pip install setproctitle
```

https://github.com/dvarrazzo/py-setproctitle

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: **No, you can't!**

`argparse` module is not intend to do it.
You should ask for the password on other separated process.
Also, the `type` argument is just a value converter used  before value is stored.