# Is there method such that password won't be echoed on cmd while passing it as command line argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords, argparse, getpass

I am trying to build a Python application for running in various platforms, for that I am adding command line options for parameters, two of which is username and password.
For password, I don't want it to be echoed on screen while someone is entering it, I am using argparse

Sample code-

```
parser.add_argument('--username', help='Your email address')
parser.add_argument('--password', help='Your password')
```

Now what parameter/action I should add to make password invisible/not echoed on screen while entering it?

Comment: The [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#module-getpass) module in the standard library should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, we can use *getpass* as below :

```
>>> import getpass
# parse arguments here
>>> user = args.username  # e.g. Sam
>>> password = getpass.getpass('Enter %s password: '% user)
Enter Sam password:
>>>
```

What you want to do is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948567/how-to-hide-password-in-python/29948740),

```
class Password(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string):
        values = getpass.getpass()
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--password', action=Password, nargs='?', dest='password')
args = parser.parse_args()
password = args.password
```